# C# создание и печать файла

Tags: c#

На работе постоянно приходится печатать маленькие этикетки для груза. На данный момент заполняется excel таблица и печатается нужное количество из нее. 
[image] 
(примерно такого формата)

Нужно много что заполнить, выделить нужное количество... В общем долго...

Появилась идея сделать небольшую софтину, где нужно заполнить форму и указать количество этих этикеток, софтина бы сама распределила их на странице и отправила в печать.

Как ой подход к данной задаче вы можете предложить?

Мои варианты:

- Создать excel файл заполнить его, и напечатать. (если это вообще возможно)
- Создать многостраничный документ xps/pdf/word... И печатать его.
- Создать набор картинок и печатать их. (наверное самый трудный вариант)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, проще всего сверстать вашу картинку в WPF-приложении.

Если ваша картинка находится, например, в `Grid`'е с именем `main`, то вы можете её напечатать при помощи

```
var dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) // возвращает bool?, поэтому сравнение с true
{
    dialog.PrintVisual(main, "Вывод этикетки на печать");
}
```

---

Ещё документация:

- [How to: Invoke a Print Dialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-invoke-a-print-dialog)

---

Дополнение: для вёрстки проще всего использовать MVVM. Для вот такого класса:

```
public class Label
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
}
```

и XAML'а

```
<ItemsControl Width="600" Height="800" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="150" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,-3,-3">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Address1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Address2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Text="Накладная:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="{Binding InvoiceNo}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Text="Заказ:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="{Binding OrderNo}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" FontStyle="Italic" Text="Место:" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ItemNo}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

и `DataContext`'а

```
new[]
{
    new Label()
    {
        Address1 = "Куда-то там",
        Address2 = "Адрес 4",
        InvoiceNo = "2222222222",
        OrderNo = "1111111111",
        ItemNo = "1"
    },
    new Label()
    {
        Address1 = "Куда-то там",
        Address2 = "Адрес 4",
        InvoiceNo = "2222222222",
        OrderNo = "1111111111",
        ItemNo = "2"
    }
}
```

получается следующая картинка:

[image: кортинко]

(Понятно, `DataContext` лучше генерировать в цикле.)

---

Если надо вывести несколько страниц, можно просто вызвать `PrintVisual` в цикле несколько раз. Однако это создаст несколько заданий на печать. Чтобы оформить это всё как *одно* задание, нужно предоставить `DocumentPaginator` и вызвать `dialog.PrintDocument` вместо `PrintVisual`. Набросал простейшую имплементацию:

```
public class Paginator : Document​Paginator
{
    Visual[] pages;

    public Paginator(params Visual[] pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages;
        this.Source = new S() { DocumentPaginator = this };
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid => true;
    public override int PageCount => pages.Length;

    public override Size PageSize { get; set; }

    class S : IDocumentPaginatorSource
    {
        public DocumentPaginator DocumentPaginator { get; set; }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source { get; }
    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber) =>
        new DocumentPage(pages[pageNumber]);
}
```

Печатать так:

```
var dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) // возвращает bool?, поэтому сравнение с true
{
    dialog.PrintDocument(new Paginator(grid1, grid2, grid3), "Вывод этикетки на печать");
}
```

Comment: Т. Е. Писать метод заполнения нескольких ячеек, вводить его в цикл и заполнять нужное количество в гриде?

Comment: @Opossum: Можно и так, но для вашей задачи идеально подходит MVVM.

Comment: Ок, буду рыть в сторону mvvm

Comment: Не лень будет отправить, собранный вами проект? (боюсь затупить)

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, даже почти не тупил.

Comment: А как быть, если нужно напечатать несколько страниц? Как я понял, печатается грид, если что-то за пределами грида, на печать оно не пойдет.

Comment: @Opossum: Сейчас скину проект.

Comment: @Opossum: Вот: http://rgho.st/87y6pklVZ

Comment: @Opossum: Если надо напечатать несколько страниц, сгенерируйте их в разных гридах, и отправьте на печать по очереди (несколько раз `dialog.PrintVisual(..., "Вывод этикетки на печать");`). Наверное есть более изящный метод, я поищу.

Comment: проблема в том, что страниц может быть 30, неужто пользователю с 30 окнами потверждения общатся. (так то можно 30 раз из одного грида печатать, подменяя наполнение)

Comment: @Opossum: Не, окно подтверждения одно (`dialog.ShowDialog()`), а страниц много (`dialog.PrintVisual`).

Comment: @Opossum: Обновил ответ, гляньте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63880/discussion-between-opossum-and-vladd).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, из предложенных вам пунктов, последний наверное самый простой. Просто рисуете через GDI и все.
Вот тут - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383872(v=vs.90).aspx можно почитать.

Другой момент, можно работать с excel через Interop (ole) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854693/printing-excel-using-interop . Так же можно и взаимодействовать с книгой и страницами. Но, это требует обязательно установленного Excel-я.

По поводу Pdf - как по мне, реализация отрисовки изображений сопоставима по объему кода с реализацией логики отрисовки PDF. Поэтому, тут уже кому как удобнее.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне необходимо, скажем 37 таких вот маленьких бумажек, если мне нужно отрисовать одну, а затем ее как то копировать со сдвигом и измененными значениями.

Comment: Все так, по факту у вас должна быть настройка размера страницы. Размер бумажки определится через максимальную длину строки ( метод MeasureString). Высота - по аналогии. 

Но вообще, сверху ответ наверное менее муторный, сделать это средствами WPF куда будет проще, чем рисовать, как я предложил.