# Печать panel c#

Tags: c#, winforms, печать

Нужно распечатать приходно-кассовый ордер. взял панель, присвоил ей bg-image и задал ей размеры листа А4. в месте где нужны значения сделал Label'ы.

вывожу на печать с помощью кода

```
    private void toolStripSplitButton1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(panel1.Location, bitmap.Size));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,new Point(0,0));
    }
```

вот результат.
[image: криво печатает]

Отступы не исчезают, что делать? помогите решить проблему. или есть лучшая альтернатива печати шаблонного документа?

Comment: А чего не хватает в предложенном в вопросе решении?

Comment: Решение для WPF пробегало только что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706253/10105

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что вы не правильно выставили или поля, или ориентацию страницы (по-умолчанию вертикальная или портретная, это как нравится). В коде вроде явных ляпов при работе с GDI нет. Посмотрите соседний [вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489415/198316) и выведите предпросмотр без печати, там видно должно быть что упустили.

Comment: ну и пока не забыл, не все принтеры умеют печать без полей (точнее некоторые только умеют - типографские например), так что подгонять размеры области печати нужно под размер внутри полей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Но в итоге я отказался от этого.

---

Исходный шаблон был в экселе. Его я сохранил как html, а html просто открываю в webbrowser. Печать этот элемент управления позволяет  легко и непринужденно.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы всё работало как надо, необходимо поменять это:

```
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(panel1.Location, bitmap.Size));
```

на

```
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size));
```

т.е. рисовать от начала координат.

Comment: допишите в ответе в чем конкретно была проблема. Я конечно нашел, но на первый взгляд код здесь и в вопросе идентичен. Это совсем не хорошо. Под любым постом есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/706699/edit)