# C# WPF Как в PrintDialog нарисовать таблицу?

Tags: c#, wpf, печать

Есть к примеру:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            printDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
            printDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

            Nullable<Boolean> print = printDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (print == true)
            {
                TextBlock visual = new TextBlock();

                visual.Inlines.Add("Первая");
                visual.Inlines.Add("Вторая");
                visual.Inlines.Add("Третья");

                new PrintDialog().PrintVisual(visual, "Print Job Description");
            }
```

При таком коде распечатывается только "Первая", "Вторая", "Третья" - слова располагаясь в столик. А как сделать так, чтобы они были в таблицу. Или еще лучше, как рисовать таблицу? Весь интернет перерыл и не могу найти нормальной информации.

Comment: `DataGrid` - пробовали?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706253/10105

Comment: К сожалению создание других Object не подходит, усложняет задачу только (хотя может являться решением), а с Drawning что-то не смог освоится.