# Печать DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, print

Надо распечатать DataTable(DataGrid) в горизонтальной(альбомной) ориентации. Пробовал печатать DataGrid, не влазит(много колонок). Менял размеры грида выводится непонятная билиберда.

1

```
Size pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, 
printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
DataGrid.Measure(
DataGrid.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
```

2

```
DataGrid.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.5f, 1);
```

Пытался найти решение, но в них все сделано через непонятные фреймворки. Подскажите рабочий вариант.

Comment: Может вам будет [это полезно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706253/220553)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ PrintVisual вылазит за рамки листа + не печатает строки дальше размеров листа

Comment: `не печатает строки дальше размеров листа` так и должно быть жеж