# Как сделать отчет для печати ,на основании таблицы из бд в Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужно сделать отчет на основании данных в таблице .Добавить название в документ ,дату и данные из datagrid.Подскажите что использовать для формирования отчета и вывода на печать? PrintVisual я использовал ,нужно програмно задать стиль ,лого и т.п

```
 private void GetProductSale()
        {
            using(var db= new ipopovContext())
            {
                ProductSaleList=db.ProductSales
                    .Include(p=>p.Product)
                    .Include(p => p.Users)
                    .Include(p => p.Client)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }

 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductSaleList}" Height="200"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наменование продукции" Binding="{Binding Titles}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Prices}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата продажи" Binding="{Binding Datatime,StringFormat={}{0:yy.MM.dd HH:mm}}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Продано кол-во" Binding="{Binding Quantity,StringFormat= {}{0} шт}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Клиент" Binding="{Binding Clients}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Продавец" Binding="{Binding Seler}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706258/220553

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!